# File browser access to Chrome's sandboxed filesystems

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems, html5-filesystem

I'm writing a Google Chrome app that stores things locally with the HTML5 FileSystem API. Is there any way to use Windows Explorer to get to the directory where Chrome stores these files or is it entirely virtual and inaccessible from outside the app? I haven't been able to find the directory by poking around nor have I seen any reference online to it.

I suppose I could just write something within the app to allow me GUI management of the files my app stores or just use the developer console, but it would really be a time saver to use WE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found it. For anyone looking, it's in (on my windows 7 machine at least)

C:\Users\ *user* \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System

Also note that this was in Chrome 11, in Chrome 13 there were some changes to the FileSystem (probably for security) that make it very difficult to find specific files by scrolling through the files in Chrome's AppData space.

Comment: is it possible to get acces to the files stored using the FileSystems API like a normal folder, with not obfuscated file names?

Comment: For Mac and Chrome 30 it is: /Users/ _USER_ /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File\ System  ;)

Comment: @Michael, But isn't the stuff inside that folder all completely obfuscated? Is there an app that could unobfuscate it?