# Where is the filesystem in html5 stored on the real file system?

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

If I use JavaScript to create a file on a HTML5 Filesystem, can I find it on the real file system of my computer?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome/11677099#11677099

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileSystem API: Where are the files and folders located](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282087/filesystem-api-where-are-the-files-and-folders-located), [Where does PERSISTENT file system storage store with chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome) and [File browser access to Chrome's sandboxed filesystems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810265/file-browser-access-to-chromes-sandboxed-filesystems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

originally I think all file is stored on a virtual file system , so files can be protected. but it's not. for chrome,  file is placed at "C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System" with  obfuscated name on windows 7. so you can operate on it as local file.

Comment: This is still true as of June 2023 with Chrome 113 on Windows 10.

Comment: Confirm, you can get your file as raw txt file in the path described above.